# Unable to Authenticate Account key in Bing web search

Tags: azure, bing-api

I am new to this community. So ignore if i am not asking question according to the standards.

My Question here
I am trying to get information from bing search through URl. For this I create account on hotmail.com and get my account key which was by default. I wrote the following url in browser.
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27Xbox%27
 After that it demands username/password. I saw in documents that username can be placed empty but password will be your account key. I write the accurate key but I alwasy get 403 forbidden error.
as given below

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
I also create my own account key but alwasys get the same results.
Anyone please help me.. where I m wrong.

Many thanks,
Farhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the account key mentioned as "Primary Account Key" on your [Azure Datamarket Account](https://datamarket.azure.com/account) page?

I tried to access the link you mentioned using my key and was able to get search results in xml format successfully.

Comment: Bhagyesh jain,                                                                                         yes I m using the account key as my Primary Account Key.

Comment: Farhan, it seems that you haven't subscribed to Bing Search API from Azure marketplace.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to subscribe to Bing Search API from Azure marketplace. Definitely something is missing from my side. That will be a great favor.

Comment: Go to [Bing Search API](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search) and activate subscription as per your requirement

Comment: of course, I will subscribe but I m just testing now. If it response according to my requirement, I will. Or there is necessary to subscribe before testing. I think 5000 queries are free in a month and after that we have to subscribe.

Comment: Thank you very much, subscription was really missing. Many thanks Bhagyesh Jain

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you switch to the **new** Bing Search API, which is part of Microsoft Cognitive Services: [Bing Web Search API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/bing-web-search-api). The legacy Search API in Azure marketplace will soon be deprecated (Dec '16).

Getting started is easy. After you sign up to Cognitive Services with your Microsoft account (e.g outlook.com e-mail), you'll get a subscription key, which you can use to send requests to the API, as described in the [Getting Started guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt712546.aspx).